# Words being Repeated in Question Index Description

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

What is causing this?

Look for the red circle in the picture below.  The word UpdateModel is being repeated.

Here is a link where you can see it live:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is+correct+behavior+of+updatemodel

[image]

Comment: It's just the acoustics on the page.

Comment: @Jeff, consider limiting the number of word hits in these descriptions to three, so that some other words can coalesce around them and give them some context.

Answer (score 1):

The search is highlighting the term "UpdateModel" for you because that's what you searched for.

Comment: It should limit the number of word hits to three, so that some other words can coalesce around them and give them some context